# Why is my node taking so long to sync?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, mist, synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I downloaded the ethereum wallet, and its taken a few days yet its still syncing. Im on block ~701,000 thus far. Is something wrong? Is it supposed to take this long?