# Blockchain taking abnormally long time to download?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, blocks, import

I'm a newbie to Ethereum. I initialized the download process for the Ethereum network blockchain using geth yesterday (geth --rpc). It's been nearly 20 hours and blocks are still being imported. Is this normal? I know that blockchains can easily take multiple hours but this is quite long.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange. You could try [this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/392/87) and [that](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/603/87), or join [him](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/3688/87) and [her](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1121/87). I will close your question as duplicated. If these linked threads do not answer your question, you are free to edit your question and queue it for reopening.